# Bootstrap 4 table responsive overflow-x not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

According to the bootstrap documentation, the table with class .table should be wrapped inside div with class .table-responsive. I am doing exactly but table does not horizontally overflows in mobile devices even though the div has the property `overflow-x: auto;`.

**Here is the screenshot**

https://ibb.co/9cZLjMy

**Here is my code**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-light table-hover">
    <caption class="font-weight-bold pl-2">Base Rebates</caption>
    <thead class="">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">LOB</th>
        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
        <th scope="col" class="">Revenue</th>
        <th scope="col">Rebate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>CSG</td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="">ABC</option>
            <option value="">DEF</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>Client A</td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345"></td>
        <td>185</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. I tried on my site, it can be scroll normally.

Comment: Any picture would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshot of mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's working. The example below has the table placed inside a bootstrap grid column, 4 and 8 respectively.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/719media/bootstrap-table/bootstrap4/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-light table-hover">
          <caption class="font-weight-bold pl-2">Base Rebates</caption>
          <thead class="">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">LOB</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
              <th scope="col" class="">Revenue</th>
              <th scope="col">Rebate</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>CSG</td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="">ABC</option>
                  <option value="">DEF</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>Client A</td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345"></td>
              <td>185</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-light table-hover">
          <caption class="font-weight-bold pl-2">Base Rebates</caption>
          <thead class="">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">LOB</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
              <th scope="col" class="">Revenue</th>
              <th scope="col">Rebate</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>CSG</td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="">ABC</option>
                  <option value="">DEF</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>Client A</td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345"></td>
              <td>185</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was CSS in my stylesheet which causing the issue. I had applied the `word-break: break:all` to `th` elements. I removed the that CSS and overflow is working now.